# How to add multiple jquery.ready() functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build web application that has html files which requires multiple js files. I need to specify some things to do in `jQuery.ready()` in each of js file, but it is impossible to define `$(function () {})` more than once. Can I change passed function somehow?

index.pug

```
script
    include src/firstFile.js
script
    include src/secondFile.js
```

firstFile.js

```
$(() => {
    doSomeThings()
})
```

secondFile.js

```
$(() => {
    doSomeOtherThings()
}
```

In the result code do only what is inside first file. Can I deal with it somehow?

**Edit:
It seemed to not work in my code because i haven't add appropriate html code.
Above code works well**

Comment: who says you can not define more than once? but it's not always the neatest thing to do.

Comment: What prevented you from **trying** to do it instead of asking if it's possible..?

Comment: One look at the documentation would have shown you that you're wrong, https://api.jquery.com/ready/: _"When multiple functions are added via successive calls to this method, they run when the DOM is ready in the order in which they are added."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**YES** you can have multiple statements of `document.ready()` , although it is not considered to be a clean code. It works, to see a simple example here it is.

```js
$(() => {
  doSomeThings();
});


$(() => {
  doSomeOtherThings();
});

function doSomeThings() {
  console.log('doSomeThings')
}

function doSomeOtherThings() {
  console.log('doSomeOtherThings')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It seemed to not work in my code because i haven't add appropriate html code. Thanks and sorry

Comment: no need to be sorry dude we all make mistakes, cheers @MateuszKomarnicki